# sam template makefile not installing python libraries

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

So, Ive been oging at this for the last few days so this is pretty much my last resort.

The problem is with the sam template makefile option.

When using an out of the box solution ie. `Metadata.BuildMethod = python3.10`, SAM cli goes and finds requirements.txt file and does its thing.
This is all great until I try and do the same thing but with `BuildMethod: makefile`.

In the makefile, I have tried pretty much every single permutation of this, and they dont work.
The following dont work:-

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t $(ARTIFACT_DIR)
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t $(ARTIFACT_DIR)/python
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t $(ARTIFACT_DIR)/python/lib/python3.10/site-packes
```

All of the above give an error of `unable to import module 'app' No module name 'pydantic'`

The folder structure is like so

```
|── events
│   └── event.json
├── hello_world
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── requirements.txt
├── README.md
├── samconfig.toml
└── template.yaml
```

the template section is like so

```
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Metadata:
      # BuildMethod: python3.10
      BuildMethod: makefile

    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.10
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

If anybody can help or give any tips, would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try the pip3 install?

Comment: sam cli is really being weird. So on a stand-alone lambda function, it works perfectly  with `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t $(ARTIFACT_DIR)/python` but on state machines that doesnt work. Maybe state machines work differently.